How to filter pornographic and violent content
I want to use custom search JSON API on our products, but when querying Chinese query, there will be a lot of irrelevant results and some pornographic content, such as this curl request, I still can't block it with safe parameters. Thank you very much for your help.
curl --location 'https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1/siterestrict?key=xxxxxxx&cx=xxxxxxxx&q=上海火车站有一个配眼镜比较出名的店，你知道是哪个店吗？&safe=active&filter=1'
I tried to add safe and filter parameters, but I couldn't filter out pornographic messages. When I translate query into English for query, the result is normal, so is it that api's support for Chinese is not perfect?
